# Want to split data into multiple sheets based on keyword

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on macro project that splits data from single sheet to multiple sheets depending on below condition:
1) Select data from "data1" of row 1 until "data1" from next row appears.
2) Cut and paste it to new worksheet.
3) Do this operation until no data left.

I tried to record macro in excel, but as data is dynamic not able to do it.

Sample input data for reference is as below:
[Sample Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QPIO.png)

Output data should be:
Sheet 1 :

```
Data 1  Data 2  Data 3  Data 4  Data 5  Data 6  Data 7  Data 8  Data 9  Data 10
Mark    1       5       78      67      23      67      892     62      27
polo    2       83      156     145     101     145     970     140     105
Tango   3       88      234     212     124     212     1862    202     132
```

sheet 2:

```
Data 1  Data 2  Data 3  Data 4  Data 5  Data 6  Data 7  Data 8  Data 9  Data 10
Laptop  1       83      156     145     101     145     970     140     105
disk    2       415     12168   9715    2323    9715    865240  8680    2835
key     3       327     11934   9503    2199    9503    863378  8478    2703
Buttons 4       56      47      8       9       456     89      15      89
clips   5       61      125     75      32      523     981     77      116
mike    6       117     172     83      41      979     1070    92      205
```

sheet 3:

```
Data 1  Data 2  Data 3  Data 4  Data 5  Data 6  Data 7  Data 8  Data 9  Data 10
team    1       78      9       0       23      45      67      89      44
```

I am novice in VBA. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *i tried to record macro in excel, but as data is dynamic not able to do it* -- you should start by showing what you have already tried, even if it doesn't work. Then you can also describe the specific problem(s) you have identified (i.e., *how do I make this dynamic*?)...

Comment: You've described a wholescale project - at bare minimum, you need to show the results which occurred when you recorded your macros, and explain how you tried to turn that into a dynamic macro, and what you had issues with. This site is for specific Q&A, and this here is just a 'please give me code' request.

Comment: @DavidZemens Very creepy how close the wording is in our two comments.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon great minds think alike :)

Comment: Hi David Zemens and Grade 'Eh' Bacon , i have tried to record macro. code is as below:Sub SplitData()
'
' SplitData Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:4").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("5:11").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Rows("12:13").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("D18").Select
End Sub
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
Sub Macro1()
'Declare Variables
Dim i, lastrow, iStart As Long
Dim sht, nsht As Worksheet
'Set current sheet and last row of current sheet
Set sht = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(UBound(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value)).Row
iStart = 1

'Loop through rows and copy rows into new sheet
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If sht.Range("A" & i).Value = "Data 1" Then
        iStart = i
    End If
    If sht.Range("A" & i + 1).Value = "Data 1" Or i = lastrow Then
        'Add new sheet and paste rows between Data 1 and row before next Data 1
        Worksheets.Add
        Set nsht = ActiveSheet
        sht.Rows(iStart & ":" & i).Copy
        nsht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        sht.Activate
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Wyatt, thanks for your help. But in this code i am getting error for line sht.Rows(iStart & ":" & i).Copy as Type mismatch

Comment: In the immediate window, can you see what values you are you getting for for the variables? So type `?sht.name` and hit enter. Do the same for iStart and I.

Comment: In the immediate window, i got value for iStart and i as 0 and 13

Comment: I edited my answer to initialize iStart and set it equal to 1. You probably also didn't update the header text it was looking for, so I updated my code.

Comment: Hi Wyatt , Many many thanks a lot ..... Code is working well....again thank you..............